# How to replace all HTML codes in a string like #39;s with their ASCII equivalents using an R package?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to harvest some HTML text and while I know I can hack something up myself, this seems like a task best left to a library. I just don't know which library can do this. I was thinking `rvest` would be the right place to look, but it seems to want to work on well formed HTML pages rather than the JSON encapsulated disembodied HTML snippets I'm working with. Is there some way to use it with a temporary file maybe or perhaps there is another package which does this?

Comment: While there exists `htmltools::htmlEscape`, it only handles a few (https://github.com/cran/htmltools/blob/master/R/html_escape.R), and it has no reverse function. I had (at some point) a hacked-together `data.frame` that had the entity (e.g., `&gt;`) and the text (`>`) for several dozen, and just iterated over them brute-force (as vectorized as possible), I don't know of a more formal tool to use.

Comment: Do you have some example text to convert that isn't working in your current attempts? What might be the approximate max length of any given string for conversion? I don't know of an R package but a possibility is to post the data to a conversion site and read back the conversion. Of course, this then depends on privacy of the info.

Comment: [`textutils::HTMLdecode()` and `textutils::HTMLencode()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/textutils/versions/0.2-1/topics/HTMLencode) have always done this wonderfully for me.